# Play mediaelement.js audio via jquery click

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediaelement.js

Not sure why this is happening or how to get around it. I'm trying to trigger a sound by clicking on a div with class `.button`

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('audio')[0].player.play();
});
```

Works great on everything except firefox.

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('audio')[0].play();
});
```

Without the `.player` Works great on everything except iOS!

Not sure what I can do here.

Comment: You can check what browser you're in, then use the correct code.

Comment: I want it to work on all platforms ideally, rather than doing different code for each.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I found an answer to this problem if anyone hasn't yet!

Use the following (works on IOS as well as FF)

```
$('audio').mediaelementplayer({
 success: function(media, domElement, player) {
   $('.play').on('click', function() {
     media.play();
   });
   $('.pause').on('click', function() {
     media.pause();
   });
 }
});
```

This would use a button or whatever with a class of "play" and the other with a class of "pause" to use externally from the player or whatever your hearts desire. Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work on several Android browsers (Chrome, Stock Browser) nor on other iOS browsers (Dolphin, Chrome, Opera).